# How to subscribe twilio number's error messages?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I have a Twilio account with a several numbers, and I have a Java back-end with Postgres DB. Is it possible to subscribe with twilio-api to get errors of this numbers on the date or in real time?

Comment: What type of errors? Can you provide more details on what you are looking for specifically?

Comment: @Alan I mean some  of errors for my numbers in Twilio console/debugger. For example - Error - 30005 Message Delivery - Unknown destination handset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to capture SMS errors such as Error 30005 Message Delivery - Unknown destination handset, and other 3000x errors is using Message Status Callbacks. You can find more details below. It is an additional URL you point Twilio to when making a request to the /Messages resource. These types of errors don't appear in the debugger because they can be quite a few of them, based on the customers use case. The new Message Insights tool allows you to visually filter on these errors from the Twilio Console (but there is no API).

A way to mitigate 30005 errors is using the [Twilio Lookup API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/how-to-confirm-delivery), to confirm the number is a mobile number and capable of receiving an SMS before sending the message.

[Track Delivery Status of Messages](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/how-to-confirm-delivery)